# EF query taking too much time and result to timeout exception

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using LINQ query to search string from table which result to timeout exception for some time. Please help me to simplify the query which is as below.

```
var lstEntityMasterdata1 = (from E in _contextRegister.Entities
                            join ba in _contextRegister.BusinessActivities on E.MainActivityId equals ba.Id into NewBA
                            from BA in NewBA.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where (E.NameOfEstablishment.Contains(SearchKey) || E.LicenseNr.Contains(SearchKey))
                            && (E.IsDeleted != true && E.Active != false)
                            select new { E, BA }).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't look too complicated of a query to me, although I don't know the inners of your database or the amount of records. Have you profiled the generated SQL to see where the bottleneck is? And if it is indeed the SQL (and not the transmission of data, for example), have you tried applying indices where applicable?

Comment: What's in your `DefaultIfEmpty()` method ?

Comment: Have you got any indexes or if you have indexes are they fragmented or not?